Neutral Tone Pronunciation and Dependency on Preceding Tones
How is the neutral tone pronounced, or is it not a fixed tone. If so, how should I be pronouncing it after different tones?

Take a class, The only way to learn pronunciation is through practice with real people.

Yes, at least in the early stages. Even foreigners who spend some time in a Mandarin speaking environment needs fine tuning because, like all languages, vocal nuances, especially spoken at some speed, is quite different as it appear on paper. Here's a funny example, https://youtu.be/XRsGNjMkfFE?si=-r4bAXuQPEGdMSZv. A famous oldie song sung by 潘秀琼, born in Macau, China, grew up in Malaysia and Singapore, is a Singaporean singer. Please tell me where she went wrong?

There's an article on Wikipedia which discuses this in quite some length:
Standard Chinese phonology - Neutral tone



There's also a table that can be simplified to:

Following a:
1st tone = ˦˩ 41
2nd tone = ˥˨ 52
3rd tone = ˧ 33 ~ ˨˧ 23
4th tone = ˨˩ 21


You may want to refer to some 轻声词表.
Although I think its okay if you choose to speak the tone clearly by each character. Neutral tone in two-character-word is not specifically taught in school as per my recon, so maybe its not a big deal.
The only problem if it bothers you, is it sounds like Ross Geller in FRIENDS, or sales teller in ADs.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
